# MQL5 Remove or Reduce dot size of trend line

Tags: c, mql5, metatrader5

I trying to plot a trend line object on the graph. But I am disturbed by the dots that are appearing on the trend lines. Here is the code:

```
bool TrendCreate(const long            chart_ID=0,        // chart's ID 
                 const string          name="TrendLine",  // line name 
                 const int             sub_window=0,      // subwindow index 
                 datetime              time1=0,           // first point time 
                 double                price1=0,          // first point price 
                 datetime              time2=0,           // second point time 
                 double                price2=0,          // second point price 
                 const color           clr=clrRed,        // line color 
                 const ENUM_LINE_STYLE style=STYLE_SOLID, // line style 
                 const int             width=1,           // line width 
                 const bool            back=false,        // in the background 
                 const bool            selection=true,    // highlight to move 
                 const bool            ray_left=false,    // line's continuation to the left 
                 const bool            ray_right=false,   // line's continuation to the right 
                 const bool            hidden=true,       // hidden in the object list 
                 const long            z_order=0)         // priority for mouse click 
  { 
//--- set anchor points' coordinates if they are not set 
   ChangeTrendEmptyPoints(time1,price1,time2,price2); 
//--- reset the error value 
   ResetLastError(); 
//--- create a trend line by the given coordinates 
   if(!ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_TREND,sub_window,time1,price1,time2,price2)) 
     { 
      Print(__FUNCTION__, 
            ": failed to create a trend line! Error code = ",GetLastError()); 
      return(false); 
     } 
//--- set line color 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clr); 
//--- set line display style 

   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_STYLE,style); 

//Set text on the graph

   ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,DoubleToString(price1 - price2));

//--- set line width 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_WIDTH,width); 
//--- display in the foreground (false) or background (true) 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BACK,back); 
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of moving the line by mouse 
//--- when creating a graphical object using ObjectCreate function, the object cannot be 
//--- highlighted and moved by default. Inside this method, selection parameter 
//--- is true by default making it possible to highlight and move the object 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTABLE,selection); 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTED,selection); 
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of continuation of the line's display to the left 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_RAY_LEFT,ray_left); 
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of continuation of the line's display to the right 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT,ray_right); 
//--- hide (true) or display (false) graphical object name in the object list 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,hidden); 
//--- set the priority for receiving the event of a mouse click in the chart 
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ZORDER,z_order); 
//--- successful execution 
   return(true); 
  } 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Move trend line anchor point                                     | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
bool TrendPointChange(const long   chart_ID=0,       // chart's ID 
                      const string name="TrendLine", // line name 
                      const int    point_index=0,    // anchor point index 
                      datetime     time=0,           // anchor point time coordinate 
                      double       price=0)          // anchor point price coordinate 
  { 
//--- if point position is not set, move it to the current bar having Bid price 
   if(!time) 
      time=TimeCurrent(); 
   if(!price) 
      price=SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID); 
//--- reset the error value 
   ResetLastError(); 
//--- move trend line's anchor point 
   if(!ObjectMove(chart_ID,name,point_index,time,price)) 
     { 
      Print(__FUNCTION__, 
            ": failed to move the anchor point! Error code = ",GetLastError()); 
      return(false); 
     } 
//--- successful execution 
   return(true); 
  } 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| The function deletes the trend line from the chart.              | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Check the values of trend line's anchor points and set default   | 
//| values for empty ones                                            | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
void ChangeTrendEmptyPoints(datetime &time1,double &price1, 
                            datetime &time2,double &price2) 
  { 
//--- if the first point's time is not set, it will be on the current bar 
   if(!time1) 
      time1=TimeCurrent(); 
//--- if the first point's price is not set, it will have Bid value 
   if(!price1) 
      price1=SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID); 
//--- if the second point's time is not set, it is located 9 bars left from the second one 
   if(!time2) 
     { 
      //--- array for receiving the open time of the last 10 bars 
      datetime temp[10]; 
      CopyTime(Symbol(),Period(),time1,10,temp); 
      //--- set the second point 9 bars left from the first one 
      time2=temp[0]; 
     } 
//--- if the second point's price is not set, it is equal to the first point's one 
   if(!price2) 
      price2=price1; 
  }
```

Here is the image:
[image: Expected image]

Now what I am expecting is that the dots on the line should be small or if not available still will do.

But I am not getting the way out how I can do that. Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove is easy, resize is not possible at all:

Well, these GUI-attributes are **`{ On | Off }`** only, one can hardly ( as of 2018-Q1 ) inject changes into the MetaTrader Terminal internal handling of it's native GUI-elements. Sad, but that is the fact to live with ( the same for GUI-fonts, the same for GUI-Comment-zone font sizes and many others ).

---

### Yet, there is a way to go:

One may switch-off these control-points upon the line creation ( just modify the calls with **`selection`** attribute set off ( as the default call-signature has:
`selection=true,    // highlight to move`

and let the user a choice to double-click the GUI-object as she/he wishes at any later stage, once the GUI-object is to get indeed moved.

This way the reported disturbances of the GUI composition will get eliminated, yet protecting the user-side comfort to work with GUI.